# QML Canvas improperly rendered with QT_SCALE_FACTOR set

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, indicator, highdpi

I have a Qt/QML program that runs on Ubuntu and on a Raspberry Pi 3B+. The program runs fine on both platforms however the Pi has a high DPI screen so I set a QT_SCALE_FACTOR to 1.3 on that device to make controls appear the right size. It works perfectly except for one thing: indicators on ComboBox and SpinBox controls are drawn the same size as if no QT_SCALE_FACTOR was set, and the rest of the rectangle they would fill if the QT_SCALE_FACTOR was applied is filled with random pixels. Setting a QT_SCALE_FACTOR on Ubuntu works without any issues.

I tried replacing the indicators with a custom one but I get the same result.

Leaving QT_SCALE_FACTOR unset produces correctly rendered indicators.

This is with Qt 5.13.2 and QtQuick.Controls 2.5 on Linux pi3 4.19.75-v7+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:45:11 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

The pictures below illustrate the behavior with QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2:

[image: ComboBox with defective custom indicator]

[image: SpinBox standard indicators]

This is the code for the custom indicator in the first picture:

```
ComboBox {
    id: cb
...
    width: 200
...
    indicator: Canvas {
        id: canvas
        x: cb.width - width - cb.rightPadding
        y: cb.topPadding + (cb.availableHeight - height) / 2
        width: 12*2
        height: 8*2
        contextType: "2d"

        Connections {
            target: cb
            function onPressedChanged() { canvas.requestPaint(); }
        }

        onPaint: {
            var context = getContext("2d");
            context.reset();
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0, 0);
            context.lineTo(width, 0);
            context.lineTo(width / 2, height);
            context.closePath();
            context.fillStyle = cb.pressed ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b";
            context.fill();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would it be safe to say that this problem has nothing to do with `Comboboxes` and is actually in regards to `Canvas` objects?

Comment: I would agree with that deduction. I’ll try drawing a Canvas on another object to see.

Comment: Your deduction was right, using a Rectangle as the ComboBox indicator works fine. Drawing a Canvas directly in the Window produces the same faulty behavior as with ComboBox indicators. I will change the title of this post to reflect that.

Comment: The checkmark in a CheckBox has the same problem.

Comment: It's most likely a bug in Qt. You could try updating to 5.15 and see if there have already been fixes for it.

Comment: Agreed. I've been putting off upgrading and recompiling my cross-compiled libraries. I guess it's either going to be that or replacing the canvas objects in the controls with Images. For this specific project, the latter option seems a lot simpler.